# System.Web.Helpers dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

In Visual Studio 2019 for Razor pages for nuGet I see the following
System-Web-Helpers.dll
AD.System.Web.Helpers.dll

the descriptions are pretty clear but what makes me pause is the number of downloads 198k and 88k.

That seems really low for basically something I would think 100% of the Razor community would need so I am not confident that I not using the dll that most people are using.

I assume this is also being used for MVC so I would assume downloads would be in the millions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Web.Helpers was released as part of ASP.NET Web Pages in 2010. It contains helpers for common tasks such as working with charts, images, caching as well has being the home of the [WebGrid](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/category/31/webgrid). While it is available from Nuget, the standard way that it was made available to Web Pages and MVC applications (MVC 3-5) was as part of the project template - hence the relatively low download numbers.

It depends on System.Web, which is part of the old .NET Framework, and is therefore not suitable for use in Razor Pages or any other type of .NET Core application.

Comment: gotcha ok, the second assembly is working as it should i was just surprised by the low downloads but the template explanation clears that up